# How can I discard results with empy fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is the structure of my documents:

```
{
    "_index" : "index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "4002809",
    "_score" : 5.6219883,
    "_source" : {
      "manufacturer" : "manufacturer of the part",
      "shortdesc" : "Description of the part",
      "te_param" : "None",
      "coverart" : "/partpics/placeholder.jpg",
      "has_datasheet" : 0,
      "id" : 4002809,
      "part" : "437297OBD25"
     }
    },
```

I need to discard results with field "shortdesc" empty

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "shortdesc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Referenced from here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Answer (score 0):

I like AJ's suggestion:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "shortdesc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will return all the docs that DON'T have that field on it.

Or you can use the following:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "term": {
                    "shortdesc": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will return all the docs that contain the field but with an empty description. I assume that an empty description has an empty string (represented as " ").